# OpenCV - Distance for each pixel

Tags: opencv

This is the flow of creation of Disparity map:

1. Take pictures of stereo camera.
2. Correct distortion based on calibration information and collimate (`initUndistortRectifyMap`, `remap`).
3. Create a disparity map (`stereoBM` or `stereoSGBM`).
4. Calculate the distance map (`reprojectImageTo3D`).

I would like to assign a distance for each pixel of the left image of step 1, but am unsure how to do this.

- Can you do this after step 4?
- Is it possible to create a disparity map for the left image in Step 3?
- Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think you mean to ask "How to compute 3D world co-ordinates from disparity map?" is that correct?

Comment: You can refer this sample! https://github.com/opencv/opencv/edit/master/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp

Comment: I would like to do the same as "FindStereoCorrespondenceGC".